# how to resolve haskell package dependency?

Tags: haskell, debian, package

I am new to haskell. I use debian 7.0. I see haskell chart from debian package management synaptics. But it seems I still miss certain packages for plotting. I googled to figure out that I need chart-diagrams.I try to install chart-diagrams but got error as follows. My question is that how to resolve this error? And I assume that using both cabal and debian deb package management SW to maintain haskell packages are not good practice?

```
$ cabal install chart-diagrams                                                                    [05/22/16 %11:44AM]
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: Chart-diagrams-1.7.1 (user goal)
trying: base-4.5.0.0/installed-c8e... (dependency of Chart-diagrams-1.7.1)
trying: text-1.2.2.1/installed-010... (dependency of Chart-diagrams-1.7.1)
next goal: svg-builder (dependency of Chart-diagrams-1.7.1)
rejecting: svg-builder-0.1.0.1 (conflict: text =>
bytestring==0.9.2.1/installed-4ad..., svg-builder => bytestring>=0.10 &&
<0.11)
rejecting: svg-builder-0.1 (conflict: base==4.5.0.0/installed-c8e...,
svg-builder => base>=4.8 && <4.10)
```

Answer (score 3):

`base==4.5.0.0` [indicates](https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package#Versions) that you're using GHC-7.4. That may not seem too old, but (perhaps since so much has changed about the base library recently), many packages are rather tight in their bounds these days, requiring a recent compiler.

With [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/install_and_upgrade.md) available, it shouldn't be too much of a hurdle to get an up to date GHC. That would be the recommended thing to do.

Probably, you *will* be able to get away with GHC-7.4 though: it turns out [the newest version of svg-builder](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/svg-builder-0.1.0.1) has relaxed the dependency to `>=4.5 && <4.10`, so after a simple `cabal update` this may install fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the [hvr ppa](https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc), in which case you can download a recent compiler and `cabal` and then install whatever you'd like with

```
cabal new-install chart-diagrams
```

or

```
cabal new-install chart-diagrams -w ghc-8.2.2
```

if need be.